# Redirect to a different domain in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to redirect `www.xyz.com/my` to `www.abc.com`, how can I do this in PHP?

Comment: read http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking you need to send a HTTP location header to the clients browser.

To do this in PHP, as the other answers have mentioned is to use the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

```
header("Location: http://www.abc.com");
```

There is a caveat that you should be aware of. The most common problem people encounter when dealing with HTTP headers is that they *must be sent to the browser prior to any other data*. If you echo any content to the client and then try to send the location header, it wont work.

For reference, there are many other [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) that you should familiarize your self with.

Answer (score 7):

You may do that in PHP by creating a subdirectory called `/my` on the http-root of the server where `www.xyz.com` is hosted and then make an `index.php` file with `<?php header("Location: http://www.abc.com"); ?>` inside it.

However, this is not the right way to do it. What you should do it create a `.htaccess` file right in the root folder of `www.xyz.com` looking like:

```
redirect /my http://www.abc.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send a header redirect:

`header("Location: http://abc.com");`

If the default page for a directory is index.php, just put that code under /my/index.php. Any visits to the /my page will redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Location: http://www.abc.com");
```

Answer (score -3):

wrong technology. You probably want to look into apache htaccess, which is generally what most people use to host php.

Comment: It can be done in PHP and they're asking about PHP. I don't see how this would be the wrong technology.